# Nested while loop counter not returning inner loop function

Tags: python, while-loop, counter, break, continue

I have a counter function, counter(), which is supposed to first count to 2 and return one function
h() and then continue counting to 3 and return the function g() and break.

```
def h():

    return "hi"

def g():

    return "hallo"

def counter():
    i = 0
    # If i is equal or less than 2, return the function h() and continue
    while i <= 2:
        i = i +1
        return h(),i
        continue

        # If i equals 3, return function g() and break/end counting
        # The current issue with this code is that the function g()
        # isn't returned and the condition itself doesn't seem to
        # respond, or count up to 3 from 2.

        if i == 3:

            return g()



    return i
print counter()
```

Comment: After a function returns, there is no "and then". It's returned. Finished. Perhaps you mean to write a generator (with `yield` instead of `return`) but it doesn't look like that from the way you call it.

Comment: Is it possible to have several returns in some nested conditional solution though?

Comment: Sure, but only of them will actually return after any function call.

Comment: What exactly should `print counter()` print?

Comment: It shoud pass indexes 0,1 to h() and wait until they are returned from h() with new values and then multiply those values with the fourth item, index 3 by passing index 3 to the g() function where the multiplication of values for (0+1)*3 is done, equal to (a+b)* d.

Answer (score 1):

```
return h(),i
```

the above line returns from the function, and the rest of the code is not run.

are you looking for `print()` ?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid print since the h() function is actually a function that needs to be returned, not printed, since it has it's own loop throung some items in a stack, with print it loops through the whole stack.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the [`return`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) statement.

When a `return` statement is encountered the function terminates, and then passes the return value to the caller (or None).

Which means your code will only work until the first `return` is encountered, and then your loop will exit.

Perhaps you are looking for [`yield`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) or [`print`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement)?